# Elpy not working with python 3.10

Tags: python, elpy

It seems elpy doesn't work with python 3.10. For instance, see the issue [here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1939) posted on the elpy repo in github. I had the same problem as that person mentions, and it seems many other people too when going to the issues in the official [repo](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy).

Does anyone know if somebody is working on fixing this issue? If so, an estimate of when it will be solved?

P.D. if this question does not belong here, I'll delete it.

Comment: Off-topic: Free software is maintained by volunteers and enthusiasts.  Within this mindset, everyone is encouraged to develop and fix their own tools. In short, it's impossible to estimate such a thing.

Comment: Yes, I know. And I appreciate the effort of those people. While it is impossible to estimate, maybe someone here has insider information.

Comment: AFAIK, elpy's author is no longer involved in the project.  It is now maintained by volunteers.

Comment: You should open an issue on the elpy github site or upvote an existing issue. You can also add a "me too" comment on an existing issue. This is *not* the proper forum for your question.

Comment: It would be wise to look for an alternate solution to Elpy (the actual maintainer is not able to maintain it, see the main page on github, on provided link) so look for ```Language server Protocol for Emacs```  https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/ and the ```pylsp```server https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/.

Comment: @Ian thanks! I'll look into that. If anyone has another alternative to elpy, please include it.